# Why do I have a very high ARP traffic while running linux 4.10.13 with docker 17.09.0-ce?

Tags: networking, docker, traffic, containers

I have a linux machine set up with docker that is running around 40 containers.

I've noticed that the ssh connection feels really slow and all externally available services are laggy.

On the machine looking at the output of `jnettop` I noticed that I constantly have an `ARP` communication of 300-500K/s.

[image]

This causes a ~1GB traffic on the network adapter (I suppose). Currently I am guessing that this is what is causing the issue, but can't figure out where it comes from.

===

EDIT:

After doing an `arpwatch` logging I've seen that a lot of unidentifiable ips are doing ARP requests.

```
Jan 25 12:33:24 some.server.net systemd-journald[467]: Suppressed 65620 messages from /system.slice/system-arpwatch.slice
Jan 25 12:33:24 some.server.net arpwatch[23240]: bogon 172.229.12.1 28:99:3a:4d:23:91 (0:c0:1d:c0:ff:ee)
Jan 25 12:33:24 some.server.net arpwatch[23240]: bogon 172.252.209.1 28:99:3a:4d:30:af (0:c0:1d:c0:ff:ee)
Jan 25 12:33:24 some.server.net arpwatch[23240]: bogon 5.189.90.1 28:99:3a:4d:30:af (0:c0:1d:c0:ff:ee)
Jan 25 12:33:24 some.server.net arpwatch[23240]: bogon 172.9.33.1 28:99:3a:4d:23:91 (0:c0:1d:c0:ff:ee)
Jan 25 12:33:24 some.server.net arpwatch[23240]: bogon 3.19.150.1 28:99:3a:4d:23:91 (0:c0:1d:c0:ff:ee)
Jan 25 12:33:24 some.server.net arpwatch[23240]: bogon 13.24.23.1 28:99:3a:4d:23:91 (0:c0:1d:c0:ff:ee)
```

Even if I stopped docker and closed all ports (except for 22). 
Then I've written to the hosting provider who mentioned that is normal to have this ammount of ARP traffic, so I guess I just have to live with it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use `tcpdump` to see who send ARP requests. If problem on your host you should fix it, otherwise find who send ARP requests and ask machine to fix this issue.

Comment: Ended up doing `arpwatch` and then talking to the VPS hosting provider, who said the traffic was normal.